# How to change default Clone URL in Gitlab Community after changing IP Address

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Previously, I have gitlab community server installed in my server with this IP 192.168.1.X, and I'm using it with no problem. But recently my network administrator change the server IP to different using 10.176.10.X. And when I trying to clone my projects from it, the default URL for clone still using the old IP number. How to change this default IP for cloning?[image]
Note : I can access my gitlab server as root.

Comment: Could you please check the rest api of gitlab. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html
You can write some script and with the help of that you can even retrieve the Clone URL and then you can store it in environment variable and from there you can access it anywhere.

Comment: @RapperAB I can clone my project using the new IP address, but I just want to know how to change the default  URL / IP address that shown when I click the clone button because it still showing the old URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, that is to go to gitlab config file and change the external url property to the new IP Address. and then reconfigure and restart

Answer (score 0):

open this file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and change the `external_url` parameter to any URL you want , fter that run these commands:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

ref:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/clone-url-wont-change/21692/6